# Add Dependent Picklist in Lightning Flow

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I am creating a screen flow in which I want to build a dependent and controlling picklist. Now I have selected the picklist component and dragged it onto the screen. The values of the picklist is coming from flow variables in which I have defined the values. This picklist will be acting as the controlling picklist.
Now for the second picklist I am again selecting the picklist component into the screen and the values of the picklist is coming from flow variables.
My question is , Is there any way I can create a controlling picklist and a dependent picklist between these 2 picklist components on the same screen ?

Comment: I assume this picklist values are not associated to any custom field, right?

Comment: Yes these picklist values are not associated to any custom field..

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to this article and this will solve your issue :-

https://jenwlee.com/2019/11/06/using-dependent-picklists-in-screen-flows/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/168148)